# Combobox in tkinter not giving correct .get() value

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

This so weird, like i am trying to use if statement and the selection in combobox to do some specific command and when combobox value is selected to 'full_name' (part of elif) they return an messagebox, that is supposed to be showed only when the first if statement is executed but according to the conditions its supposed to return the elif part but it returns the if part. Is there a mistake in my code? If the Q is unclear please try referring the code or lemme knw :) Thanks in advance.

CODE:

```
    def sp_patient():
        #Creating window
        sp_pat = Toplevel(update)
        sp_pat.title('Choose Patient')
        
        def search():
            #Assigning variable to .get()
            a = drops.get()
            
            if a == 'id' or 'emirate_id' or 'email_adress' or 'gender' or 'DOB' or 'blood_grp' or 'COVID_test':
                
                #Establishing connection
                con = mysql.connect(host='***', user='user',
                                    password='****', database='DB')
                # Making SQL command
                c = con.cursor()
                c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM patient_infos where `{a}` = '{e_1.get()}'")
                
                # Executing and saving SQL command
                records = c.fetchall()
                
                if records == []:
                    messagebox.showinfo('Does not exist!','Sorry such patient does not exist')
                else:
                    #Creating window
                    result_win = Toplevel(sp_pat)
                    result_win.title('Search result')
                    index=0
                    for index,x in enumerate(records):
                        num=0
                        for y in x:
                            lookup_label = Label(result_win,text=y)
                            lookup_label.grid(row=index+1,column=num)
                            num += 1
                    #Closing connection
                    con.close()
                    
                    #Creating column header and exit button
                    l_1 = Label(result_win,text='ID',font=font_text)
                    l_2 = Label(result_win,text='Full Name',font=font_text)
                    l_3 = Label(result_win,text='Phone no.',font=font_text)
                    l_4 = Label(result_win,text='Emirates ID',font=font_text)
                    l_5 = Label(result_win,text='Email addr.',font=font_text)
                    l_6 = Label(result_win,text='Gender',font=font_text)
                    l_7 = Label(result_win,text='DOB',font=font_text)
                    l_8 = Label(result_win,text='Nationality',font=font_text)
                    l_9 = Label(result_win,text='Blood group',font=font_text)
                    l_10 = Label(result_win,text='COVID test',font=font_text)
                    l_11 = Label(result_win,text='Emergency no.',font=font_text)
                    btn_ext = Button(result_win,text='Exit',font=font_text,command=result_win.destroy,borderwidth=2,fg='#eb4d4b')

                    #Placing it in screen
                    l_1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20)
                    l_2.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=20)
                    l_3.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=20)
                    l_4.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=20)
                    l_5.grid(row=0,column=4,padx=20)
                    l_6.grid(row=0,column=5,padx=20)
                    l_7.grid(row=0,column=6,padx=20)
                    l_8.grid(row=0,column=7,padx=20)
                    l_9.grid(row=0,column=8,padx=20)
                    l_10.grid(row=0,column=9,padx=20)
                    l_11.grid(row=0,column=10,padx=20)
                    btn_ext.grid(row=index+2,columnspan=11,ipadx=240,sticky=E+W)
        
            elif a == 'full_name' or 'ph_no' or 'nationality' or 'emergency_no':
                
                #Creating window
                result_win = Toplevel(sp_pat)
                result_win.title('Search result')
                
                #Establishing connection
                con = mysql.connect(host='****', user='user',
                                    password='*****', database='DB')
                # Making SQL command
                c = con.cursor()
                c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM patient_infos where `{a}` regexp '{e_1.get()}'")
                
                # Executing and saving SQL command
                records = c.fetchall()
                index=0
                for index,x in enumerate(records):
                    num=0
                    for y in x:
                        lookup_label = Label(result_win,text=y)
                        lookup_label.grid(row=index+1,column=num)
                        num += 1
                #Closing connection
                con.close()
                
                #Creating column headers and exit button
                l_1 = Label(result_win,text='ID',font=font_text)
                l_2 = Label(result_win,text='Full Name',font=font_text)
                l_3 = Label(result_win,text='Phone no.',font=font_text)
                l_4 = Label(result_win,text='Emirates ID',font=font_text)
                l_5 = Label(result_win,text='Email addr.',font=font_text)
                l_6 = Label(result_win,text='Gender',font=font_text)
                l_7 = Label(result_win,text='DOB',font=font_text)
                l_8 = Label(result_win,text='Nationality',font=font_text)
                l_9 = Label(result_win,text='Blood group',font=font_text)
                l_10 = Label(result_win,text='COVID test',font=font_text)
                l_11 = Label(result_win,text='Emergency no.',font=font_text)
                btn_ext = Button(result_win,text='Exit',font=font_text,command=result_win.destroy,borderwidth=2,fg='#eb4d4b')

                #Placing it on screen
                l_1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20)
                l_2.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=20)
                l_3.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=20)
                l_4.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=20)
                l_5.grid(row=0,column=4,padx=20)
                l_6.grid(row=0,column=5,padx=20)
                l_7.grid(row=0,column=6,padx=20)
                l_8.grid(row=0,column=7,padx=20)
                l_9.grid(row=0,column=8,padx=20)
                l_10.grid(row=0,column=9,padx=20)
                l_11.grid(row=0,column=10,padx=20)
                btn_ext.grid(row=index+2,columnspan=11,ipadx=240,sticky=E+W)
        
            elif a == 'Search by...':
                #Error message
                messagebox.showinfo('No choice given','Please choose a valid option to search by...')

        #Defining dropdown and entry box
        drops = ttk.Combobox(sp_pat,value=['Search by...','id','full_name','ph_no','emirate_id','email_addr','gender','DOB','nationality','blood_grp','COVID_test','emergency_no'],state='readonly')
        print(drops.get())
        drops.current(0)        
        e_1 = Entry(sp_pat)
        
       
        #Defining Labels and search button
        l_sch = Label(sp_pat,text='Search',font=Font(size='20'))
        l_id = Label(sp_pat,text='Enter',font=font_text)
        bt_db = Button(sp_pat,text='Search',command=search)

        #Placing it in screen
        drops.grid(row=1,columnspan=3,ipady=5,padx=5,pady=10)
        e_1.grid(row=2,column=1,ipady=5,padx=5,pady=5)
        l_id.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
        bt_db.grid(row=3,columnspan=2,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=E+W)
        l_sch.grid(row=0,columnspan=2,sticky=E+W,padx=10,pady=10)
```

Comment: `if a == 'id' or 'emirate_id'` always return `True`. What you wanted is `if a == 'id' or a == 'emirate_id' or ...`, or `if a in ("id", "emirate_id",...)`

Comment: yep thanks:) add that as an answer pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
if a == 'id' or 'emirate_id' or...
```

This statement always return `True`. It is evaluating whether `a=="id"` or `emirate_id` is True, and a non-empty string always returns True.

You can be explicit and use:

```
if a == 'id' or a == 'emirate_id' or ...
```

Or better yet, use keyword `in`:

```
if a in ("id", "emirate_id",...)
```